# Counting Frequencies Using (logical?) Expressions

Tags: r, frequency

I have been teaching myself R from scratch so please bear with me. I have found multiple ways to count observations, however, I am trying to figure out how to count frequencies using (logical?) expressions. I have a massive set of data approx 1 million observations. The df is set up like so:

```
    Latitude    Longitude   ID  Year    Month   Day Value
66.16667    -10.16667   CPUELE25399 1979    1   7   0
66.16667    -10.16667   CPUELE25399 1979    1   8   0
66.16667    -10.16667   CPUELE25399 1979    1   9   0
```

There are 154 unique ID's and similarly 154 unique lat/long. I am focusing in on the top 1% of all values for each unique ID. For each unique ID I have calculated the 99th percentile using their associated values. I went further and calculated each ID's 99th percentile for individual years and months i.e.. for CPUELE25399 for 1979 for month=1 the 99th percentile value is 3 (3 being the floor of the top 1%)

Using these threshold values: For each ID, for each year, for each month-  I need to count the amount of times (per month per year) that the value >= that IDs 99th percentile

I have tried at least 100 different approaches to this but I think that I am fundamentally misunderstanding something maybe in the syntax? This is the snippet of code that has gotten me the farthest:

```
ddply(Total,
      c('Latitude','Longitude','ID','Year','Month'),
        function(x) c(Threshold=quantile(x$Value,probs=.99,na.rm=TRUE),
                      Frequency=nrow(x$Value>=quantile(x$Value,probs=.99,na.rm=TRUE))))
```

R throws a warning message saying that >= is not useful for factors? 
If any one out there understands this convoluted message I would be supremely grateful for your help.

Comment: is `class(x$Value)` something like "numeric" or "integer", or is it "factor"? If it is a factor, it's possible there was a string(-ish) value in there when you read it in. If it is a factor and you want to convert to number as-is, do `x$Value = as.numeric(as.character(x$Value))`

Comment: And also, "For each ID, for each year, for each month- I need to count the amount of times (per month per year) that the value >= that IDs 99th percentile" --> does this mean you don't need to split up by "for each lat/long" (that is what your ddply seems to be doing).

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to get faster, better help please provide a toy example of your data (see `?dput`), so somebody can jump in. At least, `str(Total)` is necessary to confirm the suspicion that `Total$Value` is indeed a factor

Comment: After using  str(Total): the only factor was the ID category all the others were integer or numeric types
 From what I understood the arguments in ddply('x','y'..)were grouping variables and would just pull all the data that had unique IDs associated with them? sorry I don't know the vernacular very well yet so I don't even know if I'm using the right words..

Answer (score 0):

> Using these threshold values: For each ID, for each year, for each month- I need to count the amount of times (per month per year) that the value >= that IDs 99th percentile

Does this mean you want to

1. calculate the 99th percentile for each ID (i.e. disregarding month year etc), and THEN
2. work out the number of times you exceed this value, but now split up by month and year as well as ID?

(note: your example code groups by lat/lon but this is not mentioned in your question, so I am ignoring it. If you wish to add it in, just add it as a grouping variable in the appropriate places).

In that case, you can use `ddply` to calculate the per-ID percentile first:

```
# calculate percentile for each ID
Total <- ddply(Total, .(ID), transform, Threshold=quantile(Value, probs=.99, na.rm=T))
```

And now you can group by (ID, month and year) to see how many times you exceed:

```
Total <- ddply(Total, .(ID, Month, Year), summarize, Freq=sum(Value >= Threshold))
```

Note that `summarize` will return a dataframe with only as many rows as there are columns of `.(ID, Month, Year)`, i.e. will drop all the Latitude/Longitude columns. If you want to keep it use `transform` instead of `summarize`, and then the `Freq` will be repeated for all different (Lat, Lon) for each (ID, Mon, Year) combo.

---

Notes on ddply:

- can do `.(ID, Month, Year)` rather than `c('ID', 'Month', 'Year')` as you have done
- if you just want to add extra columns, using something like `summarize` or `mutate` or `transform` lets you do it slickly without needing to do all the `Total$` in front of the column names.